# Can a washing machine closet be located adjacent to an electric panel?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, electrical-panel, nec

We want to relocate a washer/dryer into a closet that shares a wall with the house's electrical panel (which is in the kitchen). Any code violations here or considerations?

[image: Panel is where the red arrow is]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can place the washer next to the electrical panel. As long as the door on the panel can open 90 degrees and there is a total width of 30" the panel it is legal. The working space 30" for the panel can be from 1 edge extending 30 inches beyond the other side (or actual width if the panel is wider).

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the clearance requirements, is this a good guide? https://www.nachi.org/forum/attachments/f19/17515d1200369001-clearance-front-electrical-panel-panel-clearances.jpg

Comment: We have 30 inches on the left, but did not plan that on the right

Comment: That drawing is wrong the total width including the panel is 30 inch minimum or the width of the panel if wider NEC 110.26.2

Comment: If you have 30" to 1 side you have plenty of working space.